# Battlefield4: After losing a life I lost my sniper also, on restart

Tags: battlefield-4

I am "Kunlun Mountains Mission" under the bridge I found sniper rifle i.e. "338 RECON", which was one and only I had to found as a side objective.
 I moved and got killed by grenade. Now when I come back to game I don't see rifle, I searched under bridge again, but it was not there.

How can I get my rifle back?

Answer (score 3):

Every stage needs special type of weapon to clear it, also it is side objective to find these weapons (just like dog tags). So if you have unlocked it, you can find following these steps:

1. Go to nearest arms and ammunition caret
2. Press <kbd>E</kbd> (as it is instructed on your game screen also, if tutorials are own)
3. Select Primary or Secondary weapon
4. Scroll down to bottom, you will see "338 RECON" click on it
5. Done